# Settings options not showing up in WordPress plugin

Tags: plugins

I dont know why is that 
all the plugins that i installed rigth now didnt showed the "settings" buttom

[image]

Comment: Are you sure those plugins have settings link ? Other plugin's settings link is being displayed there.

Answer (score 1):

Not all plugins have settings link / option >>>> you may found your tools in other tag.

for example font plugin you will find it in settings or tools or Edit Post page as a click or something